# Let f be a differentiable function defined on real numbers such that $f(0)= -3$ if $f'(x)≤ 5$ for all $x$ then $f(2)$ will be equal to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f$ be a differentiable function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)= -3$ if $f'(x)≤ 5$ for all $x$ then $f(2)$ will be equal to?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps to format using mathJax (see FAQ). I updated this one, but it can still use some cleanup. It also helps to share your thoughts and what you have tried. Regards

Comment: Mean-value theorem on the interval $[0,2]$? You can't get an exact value for $f(2)$ though - take the case of a horizontal line, or one which slope =4.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there's not enough information to tell what $f(2)$ will be (take lines of the form $y = mx - 3$ with $m \le 5$). But what we can say is that

$$f(2) - f(0) \le 5 \cdot (2 - 0) = 10$$

Convince yourself of this by drawing a graph of a function whose derivative is exactly $5$, and one whose derivative is less than $5$.

---

Alternatively, you can use the Mean Value Theorem; if $f(2) - f(0) > 10$, then there is a point $c \in [0, 2]$ for which

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(2) - f(0)}{2} > 5$$

a contradiction.

---

More generally, a function that behaves like this can be called *[Lipschitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity)*.